# Update table according to the selection box value in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a page in php that list the details of a person. What I need to do is that when I select a selection box value then the table should be updated corresponding to that selection box value.

At first time the details of first row should be printed. When I select the approve leave/reject leave then table should be updated.

```
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM `leavetable` WHERE forwardedtoteacher=1";
$result2 = mysql_query($query2);
$numresults2= mysql_num_rows($result2);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $numresults2; $i++)
    {

        $row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2);
        $username = $row2['username'];
        $sdate = $row2['fromdate'];
        $edate = $row2['enddate'];
        $session = $row2['session'];
        $reason = $row2['reason'];
        $

        $query = "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE username='$username'";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        $numresults = mysql_num_rows($result);
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $usern = $row['username'];
        $fname = $row['fname'];
        $lname = $row['lname'];
        $designation = $row['designation'];
        $phonenumber = $row['phonenumber'];


        echo'<table><tr><td>First name </td><td style="padding-left:20px;">'.$fname.'</td></tr><br>';

        echo'<tr><td>Last name </td><td style="padding-left:20px;">'.$lname.'</td></tr><br>';

        echo'<tr><td>Designation</td><td style="padding-left:20px;">'.$designation.'</td></tr><br>';

        echo'<tr><td>Phonenumber </td><td style="padding-left:20px;">'.$phonenumber.'</td></tr><br>';

        echo'<tr><td>Start Date </td><td style="padding-left:20px;">'.$sdate.'</td></tr><br>';

        echo'<tr><td>End Date </td><td style="padding-left:20px;">'.$edate.'</td></tr><br>';

        echo'<tr><td>Session  </td><td style="padding-left:20px;">'.$session.'</td></tr><br>';

        echo'<tr><td>Reason </td><td style="padding-left:20px;">'.$reason.'</td></tr><br>';

        echo"</table>\n";
        ?>
        <form action = <?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?> method = 'POST'>

        <?php
        echo '<select name="leavestatus">';
        echo '<option value="Approve Leave">Approve Leave</option>';
        echo '<option value="Reject Leave">Reject Leave</option>';
        echo '</select>';

        if(isset($_POST['leavestatus']))
        {
        if($_POST['leavestatus'] == 'Approve Leave')
            {

                $stmt = "UPDATE leavetable SET forwardedtohod = 1,forwardedtoteacher = 0 WHERE username = '$usern'";

                $stmt11 = mysql_query($stmt);

            }
        if($_POST['leavestatus'] == 'Reject Leave')
            {


                $stmt2 = "UPDATE leavetable SET fromdate = '',enddate ='',session = '',typeofleave = '',forwardedtoteacher=0,forwardedtohod=0 WHERE username= '$usern'";

                $stmt3 = mysql_query($stmt2); 

            }


      }

        print "<hr>";



    }
```

Here. I have two tables,leavetable and user table. What I did is,I fetched details from these tables and displayed. Then I provided a checkbox to each row and When I select the Approve Leave corresponding code should work and when reject leave is selected the corresponding code should work. That is I need to update the table with selection box value. Thanks in advance

Fisrt name : 
Last name  : 
Designation : 
..... 
..... 
.....

|Approve Leave |v|  ------> Selectionbox

-----------------------------------------------------

Fisrt name : 
Last name  : 
Designation : 
..... 
..... 
.....

|Approve Leave|  ------> Selectionbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead of `mysql`. `mysql` is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future.

second, I am not familiar with the structure of your tables and the design of your database, but from what I can see, you do not need two queries and you can fetch all the data you need with one query using `join`

third, I have used `username` field as the parameter to post because I do not know you database design, if you have an `ID integer type` field for each user, it's better to use it instead of `username`

fourth, you have to create a hidden input with the value of the username in each form and post it along with your `leavestatus`.

your code needed a lot more clean-up and performance fixes which I did some of them but not all of them.

so your code will be something like this(I did not changed you `mysql` to `mysqli` so you need to do some research on it):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['leavestatus'])){
    if($_POST['leavestatus'] == 'Approve Leave'){
        $stmt = "UPDATE leavetable SET forwardedtohod = 1,forwardedtoteacher = 0 WHERE username = '".$_POST['hdnUsername']."'";
        mysql_query($stmt);
    }
    elseif($_POST['leavestatus'] == 'Reject Leave'){
        $stmt = "UPDATE leavetable SET fromdate = '',enddate ='',session = '',typeofleave = '',forwardedtoteacher=0,forwardedtohod=0 WHERE username= '".$_POST['hdnUsername']."'";
        mysql_query($stmt); 
    }
}


$query = "SELECT leavetable.*, user.fname, user.lname, user.designation, user.phonenumber";
$query .= " FROM leavetable";
$query .= " left join user";
$query .= " on leavetable.username = user.username";
$query .= " WHERE leavetable.forwardedtoteacher=1";

$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $username = $row['username'];
    $sdate = $row['fromdate'];
    $edate = $row['enddate'];
    $session = $row['session'];
    $reason = $row['reason'];
    $fname = $row['fname'];
    $lname = $row['lname'];
    $designation = $row['designation'];
    $phonenumber = $row['phonenumber'];


    echo'<table><tr><td>First name </td><td style="padding-left:20px;">'.$fname.'</td></tr>';
    echo'<tr><td>Last name </td><td style="padding-left:20px;">'.$lname.'</td></tr>';
    echo'<tr><td>Designation</td><td style="padding-left:20px;">'.$designation.'</td></tr>';
    echo'<tr><td>Phonenumber </td><td style="padding-left:20px;">'.$phonenumber.'</td></tr>';
    echo'<tr><td>Start Date </td><td style="padding-left:20px;">'.$sdate.'</td></tr>';
    echo'<tr><td>End Date </td><td style="padding-left:20px;">'.$edate.'</td></tr>';
    echo'<tr><td>Session  </td><td style="padding-left:20px;">'.$session.'</td></tr>';
    echo'<tr><td>Reason </td><td style="padding-left:20px;">'.$reason.'</td></tr>';
    echo'</table>\n';

    echo '<form action ="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'" method="POST">'
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="hdnUsername" value="'.$username.'">';
    echo '<select name="leavestatus">';
    echo '<option value="Approve Leave">Approve Leave</option>';
    echo '<option value="Reject Leave">Reject Leave</option>';
    echo '</select>';
    echo '</form>';

    echo "<hr>";
}
?>
```